# sorting array of objects and updating state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

UPDATE: Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/15tn7?file=/client/src/App.js
There is a problem though in that the app is not rendering in the codesandbox browser. Can someone help me figure out what's the problem with that? I'm not super familiar with codesandbox.

I have an component that is basically a table of a list of employees. The employees table draws from an array of objects called employees in which each object has a last name key (among others). I want to be able to click to click on the "Name" tab of the table to put the employees in alphabetical order by last name. I've created a function to do this:

```
const nameSort = () => {
  let employeeCopy = [];
  employeeCopy = employees;
  employeeCopy.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.last_name.toLowerCase() < b.last_name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    if (a.last_name.toLowerCase() > b.last_name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  setEmployees(employeeCopy);
  console.log("name sort ran");
  console.log("employees: ", employees);
};
```

The function is running just fine. When I console.log the employees array, it comes out exactly as I want in alphabetical order by the last name key. However, the component never updates based on this newly sorted array. Can someone help me figure out how to correct this problem?

This is what how the table is being rendered:

```
<table className="et-tbl">
  <tr>
    <th onClick={nameSort}>Name</th>
    <th onClick={emailSort}>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  {employees.map((employee) => (
    <tr key={employee.id}>
      <td>
        <div
          className="et-tbl-name-cell"
          onClick={() => renderProfile(employee, employee.id)}
        >
          {employee.photo ? (
            <img
              src={employee.photo}
              alt={`${employee.first_name} ${employee.last_name}`}
            />
          ) : (
            <div></div>
          )}
          {employee.last_name}, {employee.first_name}
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>{employee.email}</td>
      <td>{employee.phone}</td>
      <td className="et-tbl-icon-cell">
        <div
          className="et-tbl-icon"
          onClick={() => renderProfile(employee, employee.id)}
        >
          <AiFillProfile />
        </div>
        <div
          className="et-tbl-icon"
          onClick={() => editEmployee(employee)}
        >
          <MdModeEdit />
        </div>
        <div className="et-tbl-icon">
          <VscChromeClose />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please could you attach complete code ? codesandbox could be a good option

Comment: Show us complete code.

Comment: Try `setEmployees([...employeeCopy])`

Comment: @Codenewbie Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/15tn7?file=/client/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to test my code (so I could be wrong), but this line in your code:

```
employeeCopy = employees;
```

doesn't make a copy of employees, since employees is a complex type (i.e. an array).

Also, `Array.prototype.sort` sorts the array in-place (instead of making a copy).

These two points above are a problem in this context, since it means the reference for `employees` doesn't ever change (because the array is mutated in-place). The way that React detects state changes in complex types (objects, arrays, etc.) is by shallowly checking whether their reference has changed.

---

Untested, but I think function `nameSort` can be re-written something like:

```
const nameSort = () => {
  setEmployees((prev) => {
    return [...prev].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.last_name.toLowerCase() < b.last_name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
      if (a.last_name.toLowerCase() > b.last_name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
  });
};
```

The main takeaway is to use spread syntax `...` to make a shallow copy (although a copy could have also been achieved using array methods: `slice` or `map`, for example).

---

Function `emailSort` can be re-written similarly:

```
const emailSort = () => {
  setEmployees((prev) => {
    return [...prev].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.email.toLowerCase() < b.email.toLowerCase()) return -1;
      if (a.email.toLowerCase() > b.email.toLowerCase()) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
  });
};
```

---

Sidenote: if those are real API keys/credentials in the code you've shared, you might want to log in to the services (Firebase, etc.), revoke these credentials and regenerate new, different ones. Just so that no unauthorised people can (mis)use these services by pretending to be you.